# Google Drive API to Zapier

Tags: json, permissions, zapier, drive

I am trying to build a simple Zap that gives a user (or users) writer permission in a newly created shared drive folder.

Zapier doesn't offer this action but it offers access to the Drive API V3.

I can pass some JSON code to the API. In my case I am passing it to [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{{myFolder__id}}/permissions](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7B%7BmyFolder__id%7D%7D/permissions)

The code I am passing looks like this:

```
{
  'role': 'writer',
  'type': 'user',
  'emailAddress': 'recipient@example.com',
  'supportsAllDrives':'true'
}
```

The response I get looks like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{{myFolder__id}}/permissions",
    "querystring": null,
    "headers": {},
    "body": "{\n  'role': 'writer',\n  'type': 'user',\n  'emailAddress': 'recipient@example.com',\n  'supportsAllDrives':'true'\n}"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 404,
    "headers": {
      "date": "Wed, 06 Sep 2023 10:25:59 GMT",
      "expires": "Wed, 06 Sep 2023 10:25:59 GMT",
      "vary": "Origin, X-Origin",
      "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "content-encoding": "gzip",
      "server": "ESF",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
      "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
    },
    "data": {
      "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "File not found: {{myFolder__id}}.",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "File not found: {{myFolder__id}}.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "location": "fileId",
            "locationType": "parameter"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "body": "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 404,\n    \"message\": \"File not found: {{myFolder__id}}.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"File not found: {{myFolder__id}}.\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"notFound\",\n        \"location\": \"fileId\",\n        \"locationType\": \"parameter\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? And how would my JSON code look like if there are more than one user?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you are sending the request, the param myFolder__id is not properly resolved to the actual file/folder id.

To grant permissions to multiple users, you'd need to make that call for each of the individual users; Alternatively you can also create a google group that have the right users, then grant permission to that group.

If you don't want to juggle with JSON/Google API, you can try an automation tool like Relay.app (disclaimer I work there), where we'd be happy to help you out.